# C# look up array within a class instance based on user input

Tags: c#, arrays, class

Very basic question here, as I'm just getting into things. Basically, I'm stuck on how to look up info from an instance of a class based on user input in C#.

I'm working on a personal practice program that matches two members together. Essentially, I've created a class with a member number and an array of previous connections.

```
class opsNextMember
{ // Creates a member
    public int memberNumber;
    public int[] previousConnections;
```

As part of this program, I want to allow for a basic input of two member numbers and then look up the first number to see if the second is in its array of previous connections and return true/false.

I've gotten as far as getting the two numbers from the user but I can't figure out how to look up an instance of the member class based on that number.

```
static bool PreviousConnection()
    { // Tells you if two members have been previously connected based on their member number.
        Console.WriteLine ("Enter first member number");
        int member1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine ("Enter second member number");
        int member2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated by a new beginner, thank you.

Comment: You can use the `Contains()` method to check whether an array or other collection _contains_ a specific value. See duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this number using the Contains () method

For example:

```
var member = new opsNextMember();
var hasConnected = member.previousConnections.Contains(<member id>);
```